# Impersonation (API) & Envelopes limit

Tags: limit, docusignapi, impersonation

When impersonating a user (using their JWT) am I consuming the envelope limit from my own API Plan or from the user plan?

I can't find anything from the documentation regarding this.
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
When impersonating the user, you use their own credentials, thus consume their envelopes.